# Scikit learn image classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I wrote this code:

```
# Import datasets, classifiers and performance metrics
from sklearn import datasets, svm, metrics
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

imgs=[[mpimg.imread('sci/img/1.jpg'),mpimg.imread('sci/img/2.jpg')],[mpimg.imread('sci/img/3.jpg'),mpimg.imread('sci/img/4.jpg')]]
targ=[1,2]

# To apply a classifier on this data, we need to flatten the image, to
# turn the data in a (samples, feature) matrix:
n_samples = len(imgs)
data = imgs.reshape((n_samples, -1))

# Create a classifier: a support vector classifier
classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001)

# We learn the digits on the first half of the digits
classifier.fit(data, targ)

# Now predict the value of the digit on the second half:
expected = targ
predicted = classifier.predict(data)

print("Classification report for classifier %s:\n%s\n"
      % (classifier, metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted)))
print("Confusion matrix:\n%s" % metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted))
```

and I read this error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'

I think I was wrong to build the array of images, as it settle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = imgs.reshape((n_samples, -1))
```

Here you trying to apply the method `reshape` on a Python list.

However, `imgs` should be be a `numpy array`. Therefore, you should replace

```
imgs = [[mpimg.imread('sci/img/1.jpg'), mpimg.imread('sci/img/2.jpg')],[mpimg.imread('sci/img/3.jpg'), mpimg.imread('sci/img/4.jpg')]]
```

with

```
import numpy as np 
imgs = np.array([[mpimg.imread('sci/img/1.jpg'), mpimg.imread('sci/img/2.jpg')], [mpimg.imread('sci/img/3.jpg'), mpimg.imread('sci/img/4.jpg')]])
```